# WPF Class-loading Error? Crashes on addition of custom class

Tags: wpf, class, runtime-error

**Popup**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in
PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
```

**Output Log**

```
'markless.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
...
'markless.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x6b0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1fa8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'markless.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'T:\#_\Programming\GitHub\markless\src\win2\markless\bin\Debug\markless.exe', Symbols loaded.
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'markless.App.App'
'markless.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.
The program '[6268] markless.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6268] markless.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This happens every time I try to add a C# class to my project. It's WPF, and when I start a new project, it'll run fine with *just the window*. The minute I try to add actual functionality to the application, it blows up on me like this. (Oh, it *builds*, it builds fair enough - this is a runtime error.) Even if I then remove the class, the application will still not run correctly. Wat do?

Any help is appreciated.

> There are many ways of going forward, but only one way of standing still. - FDR

EDIT:
If you want to check out the repo, it's [right here](https://github.com/vermiculus/markless/tree/master/src/win2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Additional information: Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'.

Your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="markless.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

The problem is not the adding of any classes but the removal/renaming of the `MainWindow` which is still referenced here.

Comment: Wow. I don't know how that slipped past my eye. I thought I used refactor. (potential bug or maybe just my build? I'm using VS2012)

Comment: @vermiculus: VS is probably not smart enough, you could have simply done a search for "MainWindow.xaml" in the project.